# Selenium returns a truncated response. How to get the whole page code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse https://www.houzz.ru/professionals/remont-i-otdelka-kvartir-i-domov

Below is the code I am using.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chromedriver = r'E:/ProgrammFiles/chromdriver/chromedriver.exe'
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
opts.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(r'E:/ProgrammFiles/chromdriver/chromedriver.exe'), options=opts)
browser.get('https://www.houzz.ru/professionals/remont-i-otdelka-kvartir-i-domov')
content = ''
while True:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)
    if content != browser.page_source:
        content = browser.page_source
        continue
    else:
        break
time.sleep(10)
requiredHtml = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
print(requiredHtml)
```

This is the response I am getting.

```
отделки выполняла ...Professionals","namespace":"HOUZZ","experienceName":"BROWSE_PROFESSIONALS","siteId":"106","siteName":"HOUZZ_RU"},"disableLegacyJsRes":true,"shouldDeferPageImpressionLogging":false}</script><script type="text/javascript">HZ = HZ || {}; HZ.ctx = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("hz-ctx").textContent);</script><script id="hz-js-async-hint" type="text/javascript">window.hzResAsync = true;</script><script id="hz-js-default" type="text/javascript">"use strict";

function _typeof(obj) { "@babel/helpers - typeof"; if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }

if (window.HZ || (window.HZ = {}), window.HZ.jUtils || (window.HZ.jUtils = {
  eventCounter: 0
}), Array.isArray || (Array.isArray = function (e) {
  return "[object Array]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(e);
}), Array.prototype.includes || (Array.prototype.includes = function (e, t) {
  return void 0 === t && (t = 0), -1 !== this.indexOf(e, t);
}), Event.prototype.preventDefault || (Event.prototype.preventDefault = function () {
  this.returnValue = !1;
}), Event.prototype.stopPropagation || (Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function () {
  this.cancelBubble = !0;
}), Element.prototype.closest || (Element.prototype.closest = function (e) {
  var t = this;

  do {
    if (Element.prototype.matches.call(t, e)) return t;
    t = t.parentElement || t.parentNode;
  } while (null !== t && 1 === t.nodeType);

  return null;
}), window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach && (NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach), "function" != typeof Element.prototype.addEventListener) {
  var eventListeners = [],
      _addEventListener = function _addEventListener(e, t) {
    var n = this,
        o = function o(e) {
      e.target = e.srcElement, e.currentTarget = n, void 0 !== t.handleEvent ? t.handleEvent(e) : t.call(n, e);
    };

    if ("DOMContentLoaded" == e) {
      var r = function r(e) {
        "complete" == document.readyState && o(e);
      };

      if (document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", r), eventListeners.push({
        object: this,
        type: e,
        listener: t,
        wrapper: r
      }), "complete" == document.readyState) {
        var i = new Event();
        i.srcElement = window, r(i);
      }
    } else this.attachEvent("on" + e, o), eventListeners.push({
      object: this,
      type: e,
      listener: t,
      wrapper: o
    });
  },
      _removeEventListener = function _removeEventListener(e, t) {
    for (var n = 0; n < eventListeners.length;) {
      var o = eventListeners[n];

      if (o.object == this && o.type == e && o.listener == t) {
        "DOMContentLoaded" == e ? this.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", o.wrapper) : this.detachEvent("on" + e, o.wrapper), eventListeners.splice(n, 1);
        break;
      }

      ++n;
    }
  };

  Element.prototype.addEventListener = _addEventListener, Element.prototype.removeEventListener = _removeEventListener, HTMLDocument && (HTMLDocument.prototype.addEventListener = _addEventListener, HTMLDocument.prototype.removeEventListener = _removeEventListener), Window && (Window.prototype.addEventListener = _addEventListener, Window.prototype.removeEventListener = _removeEventListener);
}

function scriptCreationFallback(e) {
  document.write("<script src='" + e + "' defer><\/script>");
}

function scriptLoadCallback(e) {
  for (; window.hzAsync.pendingScripts[0] && ("loaded" == window.hzAsync.pendingScripts[0].readyState || "complete" == window.hzAsync.pendingScripts[0].readyState);) {
    var t = window.hzAsync.pendingScripts.shift();
    t.onreadystatechange ? t.onreadystatechange = null : t.removeEventListener && t.removeEventListener("load", scriptLoadCallback), window.hzAsync.firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(t, window.hzAsync.firstScript);
  }
}

function loadScript(e, t) {
  if (e) try {
    var n;
    window.hzAsync.firstScript && "async" in window.hzAsync.firstScript ? ((n = document.createElement("script")).async = !1, n.src = e, n.crossOrigin = "anonymous", document.head.appendChild(n)) : window.hzAsync.firstScript && window.hzAsync.firstScript.readyState ? (n = document.createElement("script"), window.hzAsync.pendingScripts.push(n), n.addEventListener ? n.addEventListener("load", scriptLoadCallback, !1) : n.readyState && (n.onreadystatechange = scriptLoadCallback), n.src = e) : scriptCreationFallback(e);
  } catch (t) {
    scriptCreationFallback(e);
  } else t();
}

function getCookie(e) {
  for (var t = e + "=", n = document.cookie.split(";"), o = 0, r = n.length; o < r; o++) {
    for (var i = n[o]; " " === i.charAt(0);) {
      i = i.substring(1);
    }

    if (0 === i.indexOf(t)) return i.substring(t.length);
  }

  return "";
}

function logEventPixel(e, t, n, o) {
  if (e) {
    var r = e.replace(/%2F/g, "[[2f]]");

    try {
      var i = new Image();
      document.body.appendChild(i), i.onload = function () {
        n && n();
      }, "function" == typeof o && (i.onerror = function (e) {
        o(e);
      }), i.className = t, i.src = r, i.alt = "", i.style.position = "absolute", i.style.left = "-100px", i.style.width = "1px", i.style.height = "1px", i.style.top = "-100px";
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}

function getPageTransitionInfo() {
  var e = getCookie("hzd"),
      t = {};
  if (e && "string" == typeof e) try {
    var n = (e = decodeURIComponent(e)).split(":");
    6 === n.length && (t.requestId = n[0], t.objId = n[1], t.compId = n[2], t.scopeId = n[3], t.posId = n[4], t.anchorText = n[5]);
  } catch (e) {
    t = {};
  }
  return t;
}

function logPageImpression() {
  if (document.images && HZ.ctx) {
    var e = getPageTransitionInfo() || "",
        t = HZ.ctx.rid;

    if ("object" == _typeof(e)) {
      e.requestIdOverride && (t = e.requestIdOverride, delete e.requestIdOverride);

      try {
        e = JSON.stringify(e);
      } catch (t) {
        e = "";
      }
    }

    var n = "",
        o = "";
    HZ.ctx.geo && (n = HZ.ctx.geo.locale, o = HZ.ctx.geo.siteId);
    var r = -1;
    HZ.ctx.domainId && (r = HZ.ctx.domainId), logEventPixel(HZ.ctx.logcmd + "evtName=page_impression/evtRequestId=" + encodeURIComponent(t) + "/evtMessage=" + encodeURIComponent(e) + "/evtLocale=" + encodeURIComponent(n) + "/evtSiteId=" + encodeURIComponent(o) + "/evtDomainId=" + encodeURIComponent(r) + "/evtDM=2/evtV=" + encodeURIComponent(HZ.ctx.consentedVisitorIdToken) + "/iid=" + Math.ceil(1e16 * Math.random()) + "/ec=0", "page_impression", null, function (e) {
      HZ.__pageImpressionError = e;
    });
  }
}

if ("function" != typeof Object.entries && (Object.entries = function (e) {
  for (var t = Object.keys(e), n = t.length, o = new Array(n); n--;) {
    o[n] = [t[n], e[t[n]]];
  }

  return o;
}), "function" != typeof Object.values && (Object.values = function (e) {
  return Object.keys(e).map(function (t, n) {
    return e[t];
  });
}), document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
  HZ.ctx.xdEventUrl && loadScript(HZ.ctx.xdEventUrl), HZ.ctx.eelopi && !HZ.ctx.shouldDeferPageImpressionLogging && logPageImpression();
}), HZ && HZ.ctx && HZ.ctx.shouldDeferPageImpressionLogging) {
  var oldOnLoad = window.onload;

  window.onload = function () {
    oldOnLoad && oldOnLoad(), HZ.ctx.eelopi && logPageImpression();
  };
}

function supportsES6() {
  try {
    return new Function("(a = 0) => a"), !0;
  } catch (e) {
    return !1;
  }
}

function loadAllScriptsAsync(e, t) {
  var n;

  if (e) {
    if (!window.Intl && HZ.jbc && HZ.jbc.intlPolyfill) for (var o = 0, r = e.length; o < r; o++) {
      if (-1 !== e[o].indexOf("vendor")) {
        e.splice(o + 1, 0, HZ.jbc.intlPolyfill);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (HZ.jbc && HZ.jbc.es6Polyfill && !supportsES6()) for (var i = 0, c = e.length; i < c; i++) {
      if (-1 !== e[i].indexOf("vendor")) {
        e.splice(i + 1, 0, HZ.jbc.es6Polyfill);
        break;
      }
    }

    for (; n = e.shift();) {
      n && loadScript(n, function () {});
    }
  }
}

window.hzAsync = {
  pendingScripts: [],
  firstScript: document.scripts && document.scripts.length ? document.scripts[0] : null
};</script><script type="text/javascript">window.loadAllScriptsAsync(['//sk.hzcdn.com/j/res?type=l10n&locale=ru-RU&pageName=browseProfessionalsDirectory&version=20220224150841&t=l10n.js&kcan=release20220224150841288754666b','//sk.hzcdn.com/j/res?type=assets&locale=ru-RU&version=20220224150841&t=asset.js&kcan=release20220224150841288754666b','//sk.hzcdn.com/jscripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js?kcan=release20220224150841288754666b','//sk.hzcdn.com/assets/vendor_4908c5c3394b3a62b1b9.bundle.js?kcan=release20220224150841288754666b','/jscripts/branch/branchMetrics.js','//sk.hzcdn.com/assets/browseProfessionalsDirectory_87ab82ea9d7c27a777ca.bundle.js?kcan=release20220224150841288754666b']);</script><img class="page_impression" src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=page_impression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=3711251106415774/ec=0" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=client_perf_time/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22name%22%3A%22https%3A[[2f]][[2f]]www.houzz.ru[[2f]]professionals[[2f]]remont-i-otdelka-kvartir-i-domov%22%2C%22entryType%22%3A%22navigation%22%2C%22startTime%22%3A0%2C%22duration%22%3A5321.5%2C%22initiatorType%22%3A%22navigation%22%2C%22nextHopProtocol%22%3A%22h2%22%2C%22workerStart%22%3A0%2C%22redirectStart%22%3A0%2C%22redirectEnd%22%3A0%2C%22fetchStart%22%3A0.20000004768371582%2C%22domainLookupStart%22%3A2308%2C%22domainLookupEnd%22%3A2338.2000000476837%2C%22connectStart%22%3A2338.2000000476837%2C%22connectEnd%22%3A2643.5%2C%22secureConnectionStart%22%3A2383.600000023842%2C%22requestStart%22%3A2643.7000000476837%2C%22responseStart%22%3A4029.5%2C%22responseEnd%22%3A4327.600000023842%2C%22transferSize%22%3A168197%2C%22encodedBodySize%22%3A167897%2C%22decodedBodySize%22%3A1669744%2C%22serverTiming%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22workerTiming%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22unloadEventStart%22%3A0%2C%22unloadEventEnd%22%3A0%2C%22domInteractive%22%3A4384.399999976158%2C%22domContentLoadedEventStart%22%3A4384.700000047684%2C%22domContentLoadedEventEnd%22%3A4386.600000023842%2C%22domComplete%22%3A5321.5%2C%22loadEventStart%22%3A5321.5%2C%22loadEventEnd%22%3A5321.5%2C%22type%22%3A%22navigate%22%2C%22redirectCount%22%3A0%2C%22first-paint%22%3A4202%2C%22first-contentful-paint%22%3A4202%2C%22istl%22%3Afalse%2C%22cn%22%3A%22browseProfessionalsDirectory%22%2C%22pn%22%3A%22browseProfessionalsDirectory%22%2C%22testName%22%3A%7B%22browse_gql_migration%22%3A%22off%22%2C%22directory_gql_migration%22%3A%22c%22%7D%2C%22env%22%3A%22j%22%2C%22isCached%22%3Afalse%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=5234927537908136/ec=1" class="hz-logger-pixel client_perf_time" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><iframe id="history-iframe" src="javascript:&quot;&quot;" style="display: none;"></iframe><div><div class="hz-popover--bottom pointer-offset--50 hz-popover has-pointer pointer--medium hzm-pro-search-controls__location-cta" style="position: absolute; top: 620.234px; left: 124.961px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px 15px;"><div style="width: 220px;"><div class="prm">Укажите местоположение, чтобы найти экспертов поблизости</div><button class="btn btn-link  hzm-pro-search-controls__location-tooltip-close mts mrs" type="button"><svg class="svg-icon " viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="1em" height="1em" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" style="fill: currentcolor; font-size: 1em;"><path d="M17.576 5.076l-2.653-2.652-4.924 4.925-4.924-4.925-2.652 2.653 4.925 4.924-4.925 4.924 2.653 2.653L10 12.653l4.924 4.925 2.653-2.653-4.925-4.924 4.925-4.924z"></path></svg></button></div><div class="hz-popover__pointer hz-popover__pointer--inner" style="border-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);"></div></div></div><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=hzpro_upsell_impression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22pro_lead_source%22%3A%22Direct%22%2C%22event_source%22%3A%22header%22%2C%22package_category%22%3A%22core%22%2C%22user_id%22%3Anull%2C%22user_type%22%3A-1%2C%22is_paid_pro%22%3Afalse%2C%22is_impersonated%22%3Afalse%2C%22is_admin%22%3Afalse%2C%22is_mobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22page_name%22%3A%22browseProfessionalsDirectory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=5911521926982624/ec=2" class="hz-logger-pixel hzpro_upsell_impression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A64253719%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=2220830144426012/ec=3" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A57721258%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=3951072444511319/ec=4" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A65757428%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=683503507181580/ec=5" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A56354784%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=961242228540156/ec=6" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=videoConsultationUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A56354784%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=818066732422021/ec=7" class="hz-logger-pixel videoConsultationUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A52889918%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=1285249202298114/ec=8" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A58286874%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=1552085968097590/ec=9" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A61586142%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=7141577832222390/ec=10" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A64842547%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=54788068219763/ec=11" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=featuredReviewsUserImpression/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22authorId%22%3A23415196%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isSignedIn%22%3Afalse%2C%22page%22%3A%22pro-directory%22%2C%22eventFilter%22%3A%22industry_solution%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=5171107295118558/ec=12" class="hz-logger-pixel featuredReviewsUserImpression" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;"><img src="//www.houzz.com/js/log?p=evtName=google_one_tap_not_displayed_v2/evtRequestId=e9ac2935-5608-403c-81e6-56f868351128/evtMessage=%7B%22device%22%3A%22desktop%22%2C%22pageName%22%3A%22browseProfessionalsDirectory%22%2C%22reason%22%3A%22opt_out_or_no_session%22%7D/evtLocale=ru-RU/evtSiteId=106/evtDomainId=180500/evtDM=2/evtV=1645973597_af123702-e29b-438a-8013-c65280828350_5840bd6f8506b145e268c33c372977e3/iid=3337074405007876/ec=13" class="hz-logger-pixel google_one_tap_not_displayed_v2" alt="" style="position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -100px;">
<script type="text/javascript" id="">!function(b,e,f,g,a,c,d){b.fbq||(a=b.fbq=function(){a.callMethod?a.callMethod.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},b._fbq||(b._fbq=a),a.push=a,a.loaded=!0,a.version="2.0",a.queue=[],c=e.createElement(f),c.async=!0,c.src=g,d=e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0],d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d))}(window,document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");fbq("init","295742887240801");fbq("track","PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=295742887240801&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"></noscript>

<script type="text/javascript" id="">!function(b,e,f,g,a,c,d){b.fbq||(a=b.fbq=function(){a.callMethod?a.callMethod.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},b._fbq||(b._fbq=a),a.push=a,a.loaded=!0,a.version="2.0",a.queue=[],c=e.createElement(f),c.async=!0,c.src=g,d=e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0],d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d))}(window,document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");fbq("init","1374436976058630");fbq("track","PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1374436976058630&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"></noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" id="" src="https://s.yimg.jp/images/listing/tool/cv/ytag.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" id="" src="https://js.adsrvr.org/up_loader.1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="">!function(b,e,f,g,a,c,d){b.fbq||(a=b.fbq=function(){a.callMethod?a.callMethod.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},b._fbq||(b._fbq=a),a.push=a,a.loaded=!0,a.version="2.0",a.queue=[],c=e.createElement(f),c.async=!0,c.src=g,d=e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0],d.parentNode.insertBefore(c,d))}(window,document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");fbq("init","295742887240801");fbq("set","agent","tmgoogletagmanager","295742887240801");fbq("track","PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=295742887240801&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"></noscript>
<script src="https://siteintercept.qualtrics.com/dxjsmodule/CoreModule.js?Q_CLIENTVERSION=1.66.1&amp;Q_CLIENTTYPE=web&amp;Q_BRANDID=houzz" defer=""></script><div style="width:0px; height:0px; display:none; visibility:hidden;" id="batBeacon77119120009"><img style="width:0px; height:0px; display:none; visibility:hidden;" id="batBeacon161098445390" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="https://bat.bing.com/action/0?ti=134614806&amp;tm=gtm002&amp;Ver=2&amp;mid=1debbd4e-6ba4-4404-85d9-2f4810cacbdc&amp;sid=008172b097dd11ecb0575de57b6ec4e5&amp;vid=0081a29097dd11eca39ba76be5be369d&amp;vids=1&amp;pi=0&amp;lg=ru&amp;sw=800&amp;sh=600&amp;sc=24&amp;tl=15%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%3A%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%20%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%20%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%7C%20Houzz%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&amp;p=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.houzz.ru%2Fprofessionals%2Fremont-i-otdelka-kvartir-i-domov&amp;r=&amp;lt=5322&amp;evt=pageLoad&amp;msclkid=N&amp;sv=1&amp;rn=516824"></div><iframe id="epik_localstore" src="https://www.pinterest.com/ct.html" width="1" height="1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" id="">window.yjDataLayer=window.yjDataLayer||[];function ytag(){yjDataLayer.push(arguments)}ytag({type:"ycl_cookie"});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="">"function"===typeof ttd_dom_ready&&ttd_dom_ready(function(){if("function"===typeof TTDUniversalPixelApi){var a=new TTDUniversalPixelApi;a.init("njgpa0b",["8q0k4ag"],"https://insight.adsrvr.org/track/up")}});</script><iframe id="universal_pixel_8q0k4ag" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;" src="https://insight.adsrvr.org/track/up?adv=njgpa0b&amp;ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.houzz.ru%2Fprofessionals%2Fremont-i-otdelka-kvartir-i-domov&amp;upid=8q0k4ag&amp;upv=1.1.0" title="TTD Universal Pixel"></iframe>
```

The first line is the json, but it is somehow cut off and the information that is not expected is stored in it.

I need to get either json stored in `<script id="hz-ctx" type="application/json">...</script>` or directly html, which can later be parsed using beautifulsoup.

Please advise how this can be done on this site.